# Pandas groupby, get ratio of boolean variable

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with a boolean columns, what would be the most efficient way to calculate the ratio of the boolean value?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B'], 'Val': [True, True, False, False, True, False, False]})

  Group    Val
0     A   True
1     A   True
2     A  False
3     A  False
4     B   True
5     B  False
6     B  False
```

I am looking to get a dataframe which will look like this

```
  Group    Ratio
0     A    0.5
1     B    0.33333333
```